# How to dispose the repository in C#?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, dispose

I am not able to find the solution to dispose the below code.please tell me anyone.

```
private static IUnityContainer m_container;     
        public static IUnityContainer Container
        {
            get
            {
                return m_container;
            }
        }
IUnityContainer IContainerAccessor.Container
        {
            get { return Container; }
        }
private static void InitContainer()
        {
   var peopleService = new Peoplews();    
     Container
                        .RegisterInstance<Peoplews>(peopleService)

                        .RegisterInstance<IRepository<User>>(new Repository<User>())
                        .RegisterInstance<IRepository<Role>>(new Repository<Role>())
                        .RegisterInstance<IRepository<Profile>>(new Repository<Profile>())
}
```

Showing Local of type 'Repository`1' is not disposed of (at least not locally) in sonar.I tried by "using " statement but no use.please check and let me know.

Comment: please help me out to resolve this problem .